# I am trying to push each letter of a word into a vector, but it is throwing an error

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string word = "hi";
int i = 0;
vector<string> vec;
for(i ; i < word.length() ; i++)
{
    vec.push_back(word[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

I am trying to push each letter of string "hi" into a vector vec using for loop, but, it is throwing an error on the 14th line: "error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector >::push_back(char&)’"

Comment: *Please* read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) as well as [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexed access ([] operator) on std::string returns char& and not std::string itself.

Vector declared is vector of string so insertion into vector requires string type not char&

If you want to have vector of char, change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you have a vector of *strings*, not characters.

Change it to a vector of characters and it should work:

```
std::vector<char> vec;
```

---

As for what you're trying to do, there is a simpler way to do it:

```
std::vector<char> vec(begin(word), end(word));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in the fact that you have a `std::vector` of `std::string`'s, but you are trying to `push_back` a `char`. There are multiple solutions to this:

1. Change your `std::vector<string>` to a `std::vector<char>`
2. Create a new `std::string` object every time you want to `push_back` a `char` like this (This is using an overloaded `std::string` constructor but there are many more possibilities.):

```
vec.push_back(string(1,word[i]));
```

Note: Please consider reading about [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).